# How to support 01/01/2010 and 1/1/2010 date format using jquery?

Tags: jquery, validation, date

I use text field to get date in my form, i use below jquery coding for date validation(mm/dd/yyyy).

```
function isDate(txtDate) {
    var objDate,  // date object initialized from the txtDate string
        mSeconds, // txtDate in milliseconds
        day,      // day
        month,    // month
        year;     // year
    // date length should be 10 characters (no more no less)
    if (txtDate.length !== 10) {
        return false;
    }
    // third and sixth character should be '/'
    if (txtDate.substring(2, 3) !== '/' || txtDate.substring(5, 6) !== '/') {
        return false;
    }
    // extract month, day and year from the txtDate (expected format is mm/dd/yyyy)
    // subtraction will cast variables to integer implicitly (needed
    // for !== comparing)
    month = txtDate.substring(0, 2) - 1; // because months in JS start from 0
    day = txtDate.substring(3, 5) - 0;
    year = txtDate.substring(6, 10) - 0;
    // test year range
    if (year < 1000 || year > 3000) {
        return false;
    }
    // convert txtDate to milliseconds
    mSeconds = (new Date(year, month, day)).getTime();
    // initialize Date() object from calculated milliseconds
    objDate = new Date();
    objDate.setTime(mSeconds);
    // compare input date and parts from Date() object
    // if difference exists then date isn't valid
    if (objDate.getFullYear() !== year ||
        objDate.getMonth() !== month ||
        objDate.getDate() !== day) {
        return false;
    }
    // otherwise return true
    return true;
}
```

This works fine for date format (mm/dd/yyyy).. but now i need to support the format like (m/d/yyyy).

how to i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example with these modifications would support both formats:

```
// date length should be between 8 and 10 characters (no more no less)
if (txtDate.length < 8 || txtDate.length > 10) {
    return false;
}

var tokens = txtDate.split('/');
// there should be exactly three tokens
if (tokens.length !== 3) {
    return false;
}

// extract month, day and year from the txtDate
month = parseInt(tokens[0]) - 1; // because months in JS start from 0
day = parseInt(tokens[1]);
year = parseInt(tokens[2]);
```

Comment: Good answer, but what if you later need to support m/d/yy, or even European-style dd/mm/yyyy? You will continually need to support new formats, and you are reinventing the wheel every time. Better to use a library IMHO.

Comment: @Richard I would personally do that. But for some cases, there might be reasons not to introduce a new library. And of course, you're always balancing between the trivial/hacky/simple solution and the future-proof solution.

Comment: @hleinone Yes, I agree with that. But for me, once you've had to alter your code once to provide a new feature, you've gone past the "hack" stage and moved onto the "oh man! I'm going to have to keep changing this"-stage. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try the [date.js](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/) library

With that you can write code like the following:

```
Date.parse('7/1/2004')          // Thu Jul 01 2004
```

All parsing in Date.js can be globalized by including file containing culture information, so you should be able to make it do just what you want.

All you have to do is include the following files in your page to get started:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="date.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="date-de-DE.js"></script>
```

**EDIT**

Date.js seems to be dead now, but [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) looks like a good alternative.

Comment: date.js is pretty much dead project. If the author is willing to use a date handling library, I'd suggest [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) instead.

Comment: @hleinone Brill! I'd never heard of moment.js, but a great tip. Added it to my list of Javascript bookmarks.